# When running psExec in Python, it does not display the entire output of the command

Tags: python, subprocess, psexec

When running a console command in Python using subprocess everything goes well.

```
result = subprocess.Popen(['net', 'config', 'workstation'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='cp866')
```

But when you try to run the same command using psExec on a remote workstation, almost all of the result of the command is not displayed.

```
result = subprocess.Popen(['psExec.exe', '-accepteula', '\\\\'+IP, '-u', Login, '-p', Password, 
'cmd.exe', '/c', 'net', 'config', 'workstation'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='cp866')
```

Full program code:

```
import os
import subprocess
IP = '1.1.1.1'
Login = 'Administrator'
Password = 'password'
os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"
result = subprocess.Popen(['psExec.exe', '-accepteula', '\\\\'+IP, '-u', Login, '-p', Password, 'cmd.exe', '/c', 
                          'net', 'config', 'workstation'],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='cp866')
stdout, stderr = result.communicate()
try:
    stdout, stderr = result.communicate(timeout=10)
except:
    result.kill()
    stdout, stderr = result.communicate()
print(stdout)
```